# Testing that an Akka Stream doesn't produce values

Tags: akka-stream

I'm using [Akka Streams Testkit](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.2/scala/stream/stream-testkit.html) for the first time, and didn't find a nice pattern for testing that a stream would *not* produce a value, within a time window.

This works:

```
intercept[AssertionError] {   // '.expectNext' throws this
    src.request(1)
      .expectNext(100 millis)   // expect no entries in ... some time
}
```

`.expectNext` throws an `AssertionError` if there is no value within the time period, but this feels quite wrong. I don't really wish to check for an exception, and I don't really want to know what `.expectNext` throws.

Something like:

```
src.request(1)
  .expectNothing(100 millis)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
def expectNoMsg(remaining: FiniteDuration)
```

usage example in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-testkit.html#testkit).

Comment: Spot on. I don't know why I didn't spot it earlier.